# ASP.Net MVC with Entity Framework Code First Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

I have an entity called `Service` like following:

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int serviceId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public ServiceCategory category { get; set; }
}
```

The category is chosen by the user through a drop down that holds the id and the name of the categories available in the db. the ViewModel will then return that id to me to save. The way I've been doing this so far is by going to my repository, getting the category object where the id matches the selected category in the view and then assigning it. This of course takes a round trip to the db.

I was wondering, since I already have the id, is there a better way of doing this where I don't go to the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your code to

```
public class Service
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int serviceId { get; set; }
public int ServiceCategoryId {get; set;}  // Added
public string name { get; set; }
public string description { get; set; }

public ServiceCategory ServiceCategory { get; set; }
}
```

and fill `ServiceCategoryId`.

Comment: so this way, it will automatically map the ServiceCategoryId to ServiceCategory?

Comment: @hjavaher EF will load the associated ServiceCategories from the serviceid,  The ServiceCategoryId will allow you to access the underlying key in the child table.  There is also the option of caching with will hold the results in memory for faster access without having to make a trip to the databse

Comment: ok, I think we are having a slight miscommunication. The class above is my model I'm using a viewModel that sends back my selected servicecategoryid. when I'm adding a new service to the db, usually I go to the db, find the respected category, load it into the memory and assign it to service. I'm asking since I already have the id, and in the db the only thing that gets saved is the id as a FK can I save myself the db roundtrip to load the category?